# Supabase RPC functions return 204 every time, but don't update table

Tags: supabase, supabase-js

I'm in my backend (Node and Typescript).
In my rpc function, Im just trying to append jsonb to a jsonb array:

```
BEGIN
 UPDATE public.profile 
 SET checking_tokens = checking_tokens || input::JSONB
 WHERE id = userid;
END;
```

Where userid holds the id of the authenticated user, and input holds a jsonb object. 'checking_tokens' is of type jsonb array as well.

- by the way, this function is type void.

In my backend, I have this snippet for actually invoking the above function :

```js
 try {
   const {data, error} = await supabase.rpc('add_checking_account', {
    input: {
      [official_name]: { access, bank, code, id, subtype, 'date-added': today }
        }, 
        userid: userID
    });

    if (error) {
        console.log("Error with add_checking_tokens:", error)
    }

} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error with rpc function:', error)
}
```

All the parameters do return their expected results as well, no problems there.
In addition, I don't get any error messages and when checking the logs in my supabase account, the function does execute and returns a 204.

But, the table doesn't update.

I've also tried making up even basic functions that do as little as storing a string in some made-up column, but same issue. The response is a success though no changes to the table.

I've also made sure my URL and KEY are correct too.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered why. It happened to be caused by the RLS policies I had in place. Once I disabled them, I was able to update my table. Though now I have to work backwards to find what policy was giving me the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a row, the user needs to have not only `update` permission, but `select` permission as well. One way to fix this issue is to figure out where you went wrong with the policies.

Here is another way you could fix it too. You probably have `userId` as the parameter of the rpc function, but you can remove the `userId` parameter, and use `auth.uid()` in its place. You can also make the function security definer so that the function can bypass RLS policies. Since `auth.uid()` will always contain the caller user's user ID, it is safe in this case to make the function a security definer.

```sql
BEGIN
 UPDATE public.profile 
 SET checking_tokens = checking_tokens || input::JSONB
 WHERE id = auth.uid();
END;
```